# How to press 'Esc' key in Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, automation, selenium-webdriver, keypress

I have a situation where I have to press on the 'ESC' key to stop the page from loading..

This is definitely needed as otherwise the page will keep on loading  for a minute.

How do I make **selenium webdriver to press the 'Esc' key**. This has to be done using **C#.**

Also, kindly mention the class that has to be imported

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can send keys directly to the browser using Actions class. See last two lines of the following code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Stack Overflow");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Submit();

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Escape);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me by calling Perform method after SendKeys, like this: action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Escape).Perform();

Comment: In Java the last line is `action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one will help:

```
 System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
```